# Concatenating DATE and TIME in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: datetime, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to combine Col_1, `DATE ( DD/MM/YY 00:00:00)` and Col_2, TIME `(hh24:mi:ss)` into one single column.

I researched a few codes and tried a couple (`adddate()`, `To_Date()`), but none of them work. 
I would like to know how to combine these 2 columns when -->

A. Col_1 is `DATE` and COL_2 is `TIME`

B. Col_1 is `DATE` and COL_2 is `CHAR`

Comment: Forgot to mention, I want my final result as DATE type with DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS  as the format.

Comment: Is `ADDTIME()` what you want?

Comment: What database are you using?  Oracle does not have a `time` data type.  You're using Oracle SQL Developer which generally implies that you're using Oracle but maybe you're using Oracle's front end with a non-Oracle database.  When you say "none of them work" without telling us the error or showing us the code you're trying to execute, that makes it difficult for us to provide much assistance.

Comment: Things to keep in mind: AFAIK, there is no "TIME" data type in Oracle. (you added the tag: oracle-sqldeveloper, so I assume you are using Oracle). The DATE datatype always includes time. The default date format (also used by SQL Developer) doesn't always display the time part of the date. You can (I'd say should) change the format to display the time part, and a four digit year. Change the date format in preferences>database>NLS. Normally I wouldn't be in favour of using character manipulation to handle dates, but here I might go with `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(col_1,'dd/mm/yyyy')||' '||col_2)`

Comment: Awesome! @daivrz. That is what I was searching for. It works.

Answer (score 0):

DATE data types don't have a specific format, but you can control format for printing on a column by column basis with the to_char() function or you can alter the default display format for your entire session by altering your NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting like so:

```
ALTER SESSION NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Now if Col_1 is already a date column and COL_2 is a string representation of time in the HH24:MI:SS format, you can convert COL_2 to an interval data type and add it to Col_1 like so:

```
Col_1 + cast('0 '||COL_2 as interval day to second)
```

When casting the time string to an interval you need the leading '0 ' to represent the day portion of the interval.  In this case zero days.

If you haven't changed your NLS_DATE_FORMAT string as above, then you can output the results in your desired format like so:

```
to_char(Col_1 + cast('0 '||COL_2 as interval day to second), 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

However, it's best to leave the results in it's native date type for later processing.